# NO data after packaging application with HSQLDB embded

Tags: java, hibernate, hsqldb

After a month working on a java Desktop application with embded HSQLDB (with hibernate), whene i package it to a jar file, HSQLDB seems to have no data in it at all.

I checked that ismdb.script exists in the jar and that it contains the data.

Here's the structure (HSQLDB data is in the DATA folder)

```
MyProjet
   |___Main.java
   |___resources
         |____DATA
```

and here's my hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>

    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:hsqldb:res:./data/ismdb</property>

    <property name="connection.driver_class">org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver</property>

    <property name="hibernate.search.default.directory_provider">filesystem</property>

    <property name="hibernate.search.default.indexBase">./data/</property>

    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

    <property name="connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="connection.password">psw</property>
      <mapping class="com.storeengine.model.Categories"/>
    <mapping class="com.storeengine.model.Product"/>
    <mapping class="com.storeengine.model.Row"/>
    <mapping class="com.storeengine.model.Store"/>
      <!-- DB schema will be updated if needed -->
    <!-- <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property> -->
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

When i try a SELECT on a table i get java.lang.NullPointerException.

I tried all kind of paths, the only case where it works is when i set the database path to the project actual DATA folder, but of course i can't ship the software with source code. I need to have a single JAR with everything included in it.

Please help, i'm really stuck.
thanks

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand your question correctly. Do you mean you use HSQLDB to release and use it in production?!

Comment: Your URL is not right. It should be like `jdbc:hsqldb:res:/resources/DATA/ismdb` (case sensitive and starting from the root of the Jar).

Comment: @KennyTaiHuynh yes i'm trying to use in production.

Comment: @fredt my URL is correct, i tried all kind of URLs inluding the one from the root, the absolute, the relative, etc... so what i pasted there is just an example among others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i found the solution. It seems from what i learned impossible to have hsqldb embdded 100% in the same jar. You will need to place the data folder outside the project.

In my case i found out that hsqldb (or hibernate) was creating empty folder with the path i spicified (./data/ismdb) in the machine root folder, all i had to do is to copy the content of data folder from my project to the created folder and voilà.